# How do I work with Pandas multi-level series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas `filter()` and `groupby()` to arrive at a count of employee types on a given day. I need to analyze this data for outliers. In this toy example, the outlier is any shift & day where there are not two (2) shifts.

```
shifts = [("Cashier", "Thursday"), ("Cashier", "Thursday"),
        ("Cashier", "Thursday"), ("Cook", "Thursday"),
        ("Cashier", "Friday"), ("Cashier", "Friday"),
        ("Cook", "Friday"), ("Cook", "Friday"),
        ("Cashier", "Saturday"), ("Cook", "Saturday"),
        ("Cook", "Saturday")]
labels = ["JOB_TITLE", "DAY"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shifts, columns=labels)
df1 = df[['JOB_TITLE', 'DAY']].groupby('DAY')
shifts_series = df1['JOB_TITLE'].value_counts()
```

The results:

```
DAY       JOB_TITLE
Friday    Cashier      2
          Cook         2
Saturday  Cook         2
          Cashier      1
Thursday  Cashier      3
          Cook         1
Name: JOB_TITLE, dtype: int64
```

In this example, the data I need as output is,

- Which value(s) is == 1? `[('Saturday', 'Cashier'), ('Thursday', 'Cook')]`
- Which value(s) is > 2? `[('Thursday', 'Cashier')]`

**I'm thinking the better question is...**
How can I work with Multi-index Series to generate the expected list of tuples?

Which I can then use to get to my end goal, **ultimately**, to add two new columns to the DataFrame `Worked a Double:  (True,False)` and `Over staffed: (True,False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's boolean index the series and convert index to list

```py
filter1 = shifts_series[shifts_series == 1].index.tolist()
filter2 = shifts_series[shifts_series > 2].index.tolist()
```

```
$ print(filter1)
[('Saturday', 'Cashier'), ('Thursday', 'Cook')]

$ print(filter2)
[('Thursday', 'Cashier')]
```

Comment: I'd rather perform the indexing on the Index: `shifts_series.index[shifts_series>2].tolist()` ;)